# Can I remove search engine requests when I go to the MS Edge using Launcher.LaunchUriAsync from UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-edge

Search engine requests are automatically added when the UWP uses Launcher.LaunchUriAsync to navigate to MS Edge.

I use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync to pass the address to the Windows default browser.

```
string uriToLaunch = @"https://proxy.intu-soft.com/?server=google!%*qs=test";
uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

It moves to "https://www.google.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fproxy.intu-soft.com%2F%3Fserver%3Dgoogle!%25*qs%3Dtest&ie=&oe=" instead of "https://proxy.intu-soft.com/?server=google!%*qs=test" only on Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the address that your Url ends up pointing to is

```
https://patents.google.com/?q=test&oq=test
```

You can use this Url directly to start.

The URL jump becomes a search engine search, which means that your link cannot be recognized by the Edge browser as a normal http(s) link, which may be caused by the presence of **unusual characters** in your link.

Although this link can be recognized when it is entered in the address bar, it will go through a jump. When launching through the `Launcher`, the browser will first determine the link. If it does not meet the requirements, the browser will not treat it as a link.

This is how different browsers are handled differently. It's not a problem with `Launcher`.

Best regards.